# Dimensions of a merged cell (as in number of cells merged vertically and horizontally)

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a schedule in Google Spreadsheets. One of the features I want here is to have the current activity highlighted based on the time of the day.

In the formula below, understand `A` as the column that contains times (first column on the picture), and `B` as the column that contains activities.

**`=AND(B$1=upper(TEXT(TODAY(), "DDDD")), (TODAY()+$A2)<NOW(), (TODAY()+$A2+(0.5/24))>NOW())`**

- `B$1=upper(TEXT(TODAY(), "DDDD"))` checks that the day indicated at the top of the column is today
- `(TODAY()+$A2)<NOW()` checks that the time is more that what's in the `A` column on the same line
- `(TODAY()+$A2+(0.5/24))>NOW()` checks that the time isn't more than half an hour past what's in the `A` column on the same line

Using this conditional formatting formula, I obtain a decent result (see picture), but when it reaches a merged cell, it'll only work for the first half hour (in this picture, lunch will only be highlighted from 12:00PM to 12:29PM).

[image]

To correct that, my idea is to multiply `0.5/24` in the last part of the formula by the *height* (as in number of cells in height) of the merged cell

Is there a way to do this in Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: @pnuts Yep, that would totally work as expected :-)

Comment: Have you got around to know how to deal with this? It would be helpful for me too.

Comment: @fabioa. Nope, still hoping and waiting.